# there is some Colab/ Python code that I don't understand

Tags: python, bash, zip, google-colaboratory

what's the meaning the entire code? does !zip means make a zip file?

```
!zip -r ./logs/logss.zip ./logs/
```

what's the meaning of make.sh in this code

```
!bash make.sh
```

what's the meaning of the entire code?

```
cd ../..
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems this code is making a zip file of logs.

What are logs ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_file

```
!zip -r ./logs/logss.zip ./logs/
```

This command make a zipfile. Here's how it works : https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/zip

```
!bash make.sh
```

This means running the make.sh file. You need to open make.sh to know what it does.

About bash : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)

```
cd ../..
```

About the cd command : https://linuxize.com/post/linux-cd-command/

If you want to know more about bash : https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/

Comment: I'm still new with this language. I use colab for do the programming it's mean it use python as the language but all the answer are linux. is that possible?

Comment: Yes, google colab uses python. But you can also write shell script by using "!". Everytime you start a line with "!" , google colab will read this line as Bash script, and not python.